# Increase the width of a progress bar by checking for a Class .active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have been wracking my brain and googling skills and I've set to find a simple answer. I've found an alternative solution to what I was trying to achieve but it's bothering me that was I was initially was trying to do didn't work no matter what I did.

So here's what I have
I have a bootstrap progress bar and bootstrap nav-pills - shown using an image,
[progress bar and tabs for visual aid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zV9R4.png)

I am fairly new and I do struggle between the differences of JavaScript and jQuery but don't mind using either and sorry if I mixed and matched.

** I DON'T SET THE CLASSES TO ACTIVE - I'M ASSUMING BOOTSTRAP DOES **
When inspecting in the browser the active class changes from tab to tab when selected. I'm wanting to have a function that checks that its there and increased the width of the progress bar depending on the selected tab.

I have a solution but I wanted to know why none of this works ( if you want the solution I can edit and share a demo )

to call the class I've tried:

```
$().hasClass
$().className
$().classList.contains
```

to get the element that needs to be checked for the class I've tried

```
getElementById

document.querySelector 
const pill1 = $()
const pill1 = getElementbyID
const pill = document.querySelector
```

Just having no luck

```html
  <div class="container">
            <!-- PROGRESS BAR -->
            <div class="progress">
                <div id="progressbar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:10%">

                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- PROGRESS BAR END -->
        </div>
```

```html
<div id="tabs" class="container">
            <!-- TABS -->
        <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
            <li id="pills-contactDetails-tab" class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="true">Contact Details</a>
            </li>
            <li id="pills-FAQ1-tab" class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-FAQ1" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-FAQ1" aria-selected="false">FAQ 1</a>
            </li>
            <li id="pills-FAQ2-tab" class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link"  data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-FAQ2" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-FAQ2" aria-selected="false">FAQ 2</a>
            </li>
            <li id="pills-FAQ3-tab" class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-FAQ3" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-FAQ3" aria-selected="false">FAQ 3</a>
            </li>
            <li id="pills-FAQ4-tab" class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-FAQ4" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-FAQ4" aria-selected="false">FAQ 4</a>
            </li>
            <li id="pills-FAQ5-tab" class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-FAQ5" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-FAQ5" aria-selected="false">FAQ 5</a>
            </li>
            <li id="pills-FAQ6-tab" class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-FAQ6" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-FAQ6" aria-selected="false">FAQ 6</a>
            </li>
            <li id="pills-FAQ7-tab" class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-FAQ7" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-FAQ7" aria-selected="false">FAQ 7</a>
            </li>
            <li id="pills-FAQ8-tab" class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-FAQ8" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-FAQ8" aria-selected="false">FAQ 8</a>
            </li>
            <li id="pills-FAQ9-tab" class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-FAQ9" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-FAQ9" aria-selected="false">FAQ 9</a>
            </li>
            <li id="pills-requestCallBack-tab" class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-request" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-requestCallBack" aria-selected="false">Request Callback</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contactDetails-tab">1</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-FAQ1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-FAQ1-tab">2</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-FAQ2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-FAQ2-tab">3</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-FAQ3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-FAQ3-tab">4</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-FAQ4" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-FAQ4-tab">5</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-FAQ5" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-FAQ5-tab">6</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-FAQ6" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-FAQ6-tab">7</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-FAQ7" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-FAQ7-tab">8</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-FAQ8" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-FAQ8-tab">9</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-FAQ9" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-FAQ9-tab">10</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-request" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-requestCallBack-tab">11</div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".nav-item").click(progress());
});

function steps() {
    const element = document.getElementById("#progressbar");


    if ($("pills-contactDetails-tab").hasClass(".active")) {
        element.style.width = "0%";

    }
    else if ($("#pills-FAQ1-tab").hasClass(".active")) {
        element.style.width = "9.1%";

    }

    else if ($("#pills-FAQ2-tab").hasClass(".active")) {
        element.style.width ="18.2%";

    }
    else if ($("#pills-FAQ3-tab").hasClass(".active")) {
        element.style.width ="27.3%";

    }

}
```

Comment: So you basically want to change width if a tab becomes visible correct? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#events. There are events on tabs that let you know when a tab became visible or not

Comment: thank you for the direction!  il take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you would use the show event on the tabs to make the progress bar change. also the element variable was null because it had '#progressbar' instead of 'progressbar'. The below example should run fine for you.

I would suggest to change the if elseif elseif in to a switch statement later.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
//  $(".nav-item").click(progress());

  $(".nav-link[data-toggle=pill]").on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
    e.target // newly activated tab
    e.relatedTarget // previous active tab
    var activeTabId = $(e.target).parent().attr('id');
      console.log(activeTabId);
     var element = document.getElementById("progressbar");


  if (activeTabId == "pills-contactDetails-tab") {
    element.style.width = "0%";

  } else if ( activeTabId == "pills-FAQ1-tab") {
    element.style.width = "9.1%";

  } else if (activeTabId == "pills-FAQ2-tab") {
    element.style.width = "18.2%";

  } else if (activeTabId == "pills-FAQ3-tab") {
    element.style.width = "27.3%";

  }

  })

});



function steps() {
  const element = document.getElementById("#progressbar");


  if ($("pills-contactDetails-tab").hasClass(".active")) {
    element.style.width = "0%";

  } else if ($("#pills-FAQ1-tab").hasClass(".active")) {
    element.style.width = "9.1%";

  } else if ($("#pills-FAQ2-tab").hasClass(".active")) {
    element.style.width = "18.2%";

  } else if ($("#pills-FAQ3-tab").hasClass(".active")) {
    element.style.width = "27.3%";

  }

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="progress">
                <div id="progressbar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:10%">

                </div>
            </div>

<div id="tabs" class="container">
            <!-- TABS -->
        <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
            <li id="pills-contactDetails-tab" class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="true">Contact Details</a>
            </li>
            <li id="pills-FAQ1-tab" class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-FAQ1" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-FAQ1" aria-selected="false">FAQ 1</a>
            </li>
            <li id="pills-FAQ2-tab" class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link"  data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-FAQ2" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-FAQ2" aria-selected="false">FAQ 2</a>
            </li>
            <li id="pills-FAQ3-tab" class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-FAQ3" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-FAQ3" aria-selected="false">FAQ 3</a>
            </li>
            <li id="pills-FAQ4-tab" class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-FAQ4" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-FAQ4" aria-selected="false">FAQ 4</a>
            </li>
            <li id="pills-FAQ5-tab" class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-FAQ5" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-FAQ5" aria-selected="false">FAQ 5</a>
            </li>
            <li id="pills-FAQ6-tab" class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-FAQ6" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-FAQ6" aria-selected="false">FAQ 6</a>
            </li>
            <li id="pills-FAQ7-tab" class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-FAQ7" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-FAQ7" aria-selected="false">FAQ 7</a>
            </li>
            <li id="pills-FAQ8-tab" class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-FAQ8" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-FAQ8" aria-selected="false">FAQ 8</a>
            </li>
            <li id="pills-FAQ9-tab" class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-FAQ9" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-FAQ9" aria-selected="false">FAQ 9</a>
            </li>
            <li id="pills-requestCallBack-tab" class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-request" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-requestCallBack" aria-selected="false">Request Callback</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contactDetails-tab">1</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-FAQ1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-FAQ1-tab">2</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-FAQ2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-FAQ2-tab">3</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-FAQ3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-FAQ3-tab">4</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-FAQ4" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-FAQ4-tab">5</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-FAQ5" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-FAQ5-tab">6</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-FAQ6" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-FAQ6-tab">7</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-FAQ7" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-FAQ7-tab">8</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-FAQ8" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-FAQ8-tab">9</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-FAQ9" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-FAQ9-tab">10</div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-request" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-requestCallBack-tab">11</div>

        </div>
    </div>
```